# pandas csv to psql: additional column is being generated in output (?)

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, export-to-csv

My .csv-generated psql database is being created with an extra column and I cant figure out why...

in.csv:

```
Box,Color,Contents`  
1,Blue,"thing one [version 1] [dd/mm/yyyy]  
thing two [version 1] [dd/mm/yyyy]  
thing three [version 1] [dd/mm/yyyy]  
2,Red,thing four [version 1] [dd/mm/yyyy]
3,Green,"thing five [version 1] [dd/mm/yyyy]  
thing six [version 1] [dd/mm/yyyy]
```

convert.py (redacted)

```
## begin imports
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy_utils import database_exists, create_database
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
import sys
import csv
import time

## begin cellmaxmod
csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)
maxInt = sys.maxsize
decrement = True
while decrement:
    # decrease the maxInt value by factor 10 
    # as long as the OverflowError occurs.

    decrement = False
    try:
        csv.field_size_limit(maxInt)
    except OverflowError:
        maxInt = int(maxInt/10)
        decrement = True

## begin csv2df
df = pd.read_csv('in.csv', encoding='utf-8', engine='python', na_values=['.'])

## begin df2csv
df.to_csv('out.csv')

## begin csv2psql
class MyDB(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.params = config()

    def create_new_db(self, newdb):
        user, host, port = self.params['user'], self.params['host'], self.params['port']

        pw = self.params['password']
        url = 'postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'
        url = url.format(user, pw, host, port, newdb)

        self.engine = create_engine(url, client_encoding='utf8')
        if not database_exists(self.engine.url):
            create_database(self.engine.url)
        # print(database_exists(engine.url))

def df2postgres(engine, df):
    con = engine.connect()
    df.to_sql(name='data', con=con, if_exists='replace', index=True, chunksize=10)

    return con

if __name__ == '__main__':

    testdb = MyDB()
    testdb.create_new_db('converted')
    engn = testdb.engine
    df = pd.read_csv('out.csv', encoding='utf-8', engine='python', na_values=['.'])
    pd.isnull(df)
```

out.csv (notice the new column):

```
,Box,Color,Contents
0,1,Blue,"thing one [version 1] [dd/mm/yyyy]
thing two [version 1] [dd/mm/yyyy]
thing three [version 1] [dd/mm/yyyy]
1,2,Red,thing four [version 1] [dd/mm/yyyy]
2,3,Green,"thing five [version 1] [dd/mm/yyyy]
thing six [version 1] [dd/mm/yyyy]
```

pg4admin screenshot of psql database:

[image]

Question:  where is the second column; *"Unamed: 0"* coming from and how might I stop its generation or script its safe removal within the out.csv prior to database creation?

~tnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My .csv-generated psql database is being created with an extra column
>   and I cant figure out why...

That extra column in the `out.csv` is actually the data frame index. To remove it, you have to pass the `index=False` parameter value to the `to_csv()` method.

```
df.to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
```

That will generate your `out.csv` file without the additional column.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: it does help... thank you.  but im still a little lost. if the second column "unnamed: 0" is the index, then why is there an index column to its left, @ col1?  i apparently am generating two indices?
ill pass the false and see if i wind up with only 1 (or none?).

tnx

update:

wait a sec, I think im following now.
i create the csv without specifying false (therfore, my first index)

and then later, im passing index = true for the sql generation as well:
        df.to_sql(name='data', con=con, if_exists='replace', index=True, chunksize=10)  

so naturally; two indices.
thank you.

Comment: actually, you were correct, however it appears as though the solution is now 'index_col, as in "index_col='Box'".  problem solved.  (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv)